# Multiplying two matrices with Java

Tags: java, r, matrix, jama

I try to multiplying 2 matrices.
I tried with R software: check this thread: [Multiplying two matrices in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894068/multiplying-two-matrices-in-r)

Now i try to do the same thing in Java.

I use Jama library for matrix.

my power function

```
public Matrix power(Matrix M, double p) {
    EigenvalueDecomposition evd = M.eig();
    Matrix D = evd.getD();
    for (int i = 0; i < D.getColumnDimension(); i++) {
        D.set(i, i, Math.pow(D.get(i, i), p));
    }

    Matrix V = evd.getV();

    return V.times(D.times(V.transpose()));
}


double[][] matDouble1 = {{0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25}};
double[][] matDouble2 = {{0, 0, 1, 0},
                       {0.333, 0, 0.333, 0.333},
                       {1, 0, 0, 0},
                       {0, 1, 0, 0}};
Matrix mat1 = new Matrix(matDouble1);
Matrix mat2 = new Matrix(matDouble2);
mat2 = power(mat2, 10000);
mat1 = mat1.times(mat2.transpose());
```

When is display mat1 i get:

```
0.25018740608813655 0.2498123125257854  0.2501874060881363  0.24981231252578548
```

instead of

```
0.5 0 0.5 0
```

with R i do

```
mpower = function(M,p) {
     A = as.matrix(M)

    if (dim(A)[1] != dim(A)[2]) stop("not a square matrix")

    # M^{-1} = the matrix inverse of M
    if (p==-1) return(solve(A))

    # M^0 = I
    if (p==0) return(diag(1,dim(A)[1],dim(A)[2]))

    # M^1 = M
    if (p==1) return(A)

    if (p < -1) stop("only powers >= -1 allowed")
    if (p != as.integer(p)) stop("only integer powers allowed")

    R = A
    for (i in 2:p) {
        R = R %*% A
    }
    return(R)
```

}

```
mat1<-matrix(c(0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25),nrow=1)
mat2<-matrix(c(0,0,1,0,0.3,0,0.3,0.3,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0),nrow=4)
mat1%*%t(mpower(mat2,10000))
```

i get

```
[1,] 0.4996252    0 0.4996252    0
```

Comment: with r      i get: 0.4996252    0 0.4996252    0

Answer (score 2):

Just did this in MATLAB:

```
>> a = [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]

a =

    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500

>> b= [0 0 1 0; .333 0 .333 .333; 1 0 0 0; 0 1 0 0]

b =

         0         0    1.0000         0
    0.3330         0    0.3330    0.3330
    1.0000         0         0         0
         0    1.0000         0         0

>> c = b^10000

c =

    1.0000         0         0         0
    0.4993         0    0.4993         0
         0         0    1.0000         0
    0.4993         0    0.4993         0

>> a*c'

ans =

    0.2500    0.2496    0.2500    0.2496
```

The Java code is working correctly. However:

```
>> a*c

ans =

    0.4996         0    0.4996         0
```

So your matrix is getting transposed in the R code because you need `byrow = TRUE` in your `as.matrix` statements.

To clarify:

```
mat2<-matrix(c(0,0,1,0,0.3,0,0.3,0.3,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0),nrow=4)
```

Creates the matrix

```
     0       0.3         1         0
     0         0         0         1
     1       0.3         0         0
     0       0.3         0         0
```

You want

```
mat2<-matrix(c(0,0,1,0,0.3,0,0.3,0.3,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0),nrow=4,byrow=TRUE)
```

Which creates the matrix

```
     0         0         1         0
   0.3         0       0.3       0.3
     1         0         0         0
     0         1         0         0
```

Comment: Or you shouldn't have transposed the matrix in the Java code, if you want that equation.

Comment: Same? Are you telling me that mat2 ended up symmetric?

Comment: on this page: http://benhur.teluq.uqam.ca/SPIP/inf6104/article.php3?id_article=53&id_rubrique=13&sem=Semaine%2011 you can see the result: http://static.inky.ws/image/1595/image.jpg

Comment: i just search a way to obtain the same value then in R (without byrow=TRUE)

Comment: You should have gotten that from `mat1.times(mat2)`. Maybe if you print `mat2` it might help figure out what is happening.

Comment: without power i get: 0.33325 0.25 0.33325 0.08325

Comment: power seem to be the proble i changed it to: public Matrix              power2(Matrix m, double p){
        for(int i=0;i<p;i++){
            m=m.times(m);
        }
        return m;
    }